# UWP поиск среди элементов ListView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Я создаю список элементов ListView по классу, но список получается достаточно большой. Как осуществить поиск среди этих элементов(выборку элементов по типу как в AutoSuggestBox, т.е ввожу определенное имя и лист из всех элементов оставляет только те, где встречается та строка, что я ввел)?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под поиском? Поиск чего? И сколько элементов в списке?

Comment: @VladD выборка элементов по типу как в AutoSuggestBox, т.е ввожу определенное имя и лист из всех элементов оставляет только те, где встречается та строка, что я ввел. Элементов более 60+

Comment: вы воспользуйтесь здесь поиском, уже были подобные вопросы, только касались они WPF, но принципиально это ничего не меняет. Даю подсказку: нужно использовать LINQ запрос для выбора из большой коллекции в малую, которую вы привязываете к своему ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть список, есть текстбокс.

1. В текстбокс вводите слово.
2. Берете коллекцию, которая привязана к списку, фильтруете ее и все.

Примерно так:

```
КоллекцияВашихЭлементов = КоллекцияВашихЭлементов.FindAll(x => x.Name == "введенноеСлово");
```

Comment: а может так? (x => x.Name.Contains("введенноеСлово")

Comment: Может и так. Смотря насколько точное совпадение нужно.

Comment: А если моя коллекция - лист привязанный к классу?

Comment: Без разницы. Главное чтобы свойство поддерживало INotifyPropertyChanged